# Golang, how to dynamically choose implementation of an interface

Tags: go, struct

Is it possible to dynamically choose an implementation for an interface in golang?
Below is the code snippet, that is implement a calculator function.

```
type operation interface {
    do(operand1, operand2 int) (int, error)
}
type sum struct {
    operator byte
}

func (s sum) do(operand1, operand2 int) (int, error) {
    return operand1 + operand2, nil
}

type subtract struct {
    operator byte
}

func (s subtract) do(operand1, operand2 int) (int, error) {
    return operand1 - operand2, nil
}

type multiplication struct {
    operator byte
}

func (s multiplication) do(operand1, operand2 int) (int, error) {
    return operand1 * operand2, nil
}

type division struct {
    operator byte
}

func (s division) do(operand1, operand2 int) (int, error) {
    if operand2 == 0 {
        return 0, ErrDivisionByZero
    }
    return operand1 / operand2, nil
}

type power struct {
    operator byte 
}

func (s power) do(operand1, operand2 int) (int, error) {
    return operand1 ^ operand2, nil
}
```

Input is be an expression ex : 2 + 3. From the input, operator will be extracted. And based on the operator, I want to invoke the  do method of the corresponding implementing struct. I understand, based on the operator, that we can use a switch clause to instantiate corresponding structs. But is there a way to do it dynamically? So that in the future, if the application has to be extended to support a new operator. It is a matter of adding a new struct that implements the operation interface.

Comment: No, *you* need to *explicitly* map the operator to the implementation. How you do that, whether by using an expression `switch`, or a `map`, or `reflect`, or something else, is entirely up to you. And anytime you add a new, or remove an old, operation you need to update the "mapping".

Comment: @mkopriva you should post this as an answer (maybe with a short example)